# Change scorestreaks once I obtain it

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

On PS3, how do I switch between scorestreaks once I've obtained them?

Comment: Do you mean switching between the 3 you currently have active during a game?

Comment: @Lyrical If you have two of your three was how it was originally worded.

Answer (score 3):

D-Pad Up and D-Pad Down should be the process to change between scorestreaks.

That's coming from the Xbox 360 edition though.

Comment: Pretty sure you can in BO2.

Comment: @Aaron128l You're 100% correct, you can :)